# How to detect the exact location of a click?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I'm trying to get the exact location of click in Unity using C#, but I have no idea how to determine it. I tried using raycast and I get a quite accurate location, but it's just rounded to one decimal. It is a little bit too big of a mistake for me. So how can I get a totally accurate location?

My code is as follows:

```
RaycastHit hit;
Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(holdPosition);
if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity, 1<<15)) {
    Debug.Log(hit.point);
}
```

And I get a result like (0.5, 1.3, -5.0), but I want a precision of up to 4 or 5 decimals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually do get more precise results than that. Values in the console are rounded. The actual floating point values do have a higher precision. If you want to see what that is, you could use a format specifier like:

```
Debug.Log(hit.point.ToString("F4"));
```

Where `"F4"` is a [standard numeric format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx). That should show you more precise values.

Comment: Thank u!! Wow i feel so much better now! :D

Comment: You're welcome. Glad that helped. :) It's admittedly a bit surprising at first.

Answer (score 1):

```
Debug.Log(hit.point.x);
Debug.Log(hit.point.y);
Debug.Log(hit.point.z);
```

Will give you more precise values.